# Query String value is missing in update icon : CGridView (Yii)

Tags: yii, grid

I'm using Yii , In CGridView if I click update icon, nothing is comming (in quwey string) after `id=`

```
URL?r=employes/update&id=
```

View

```
<?php
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array( 
 'id'=>'employee-grid',
 'dataProvider'=>$model->EmpList(),
 'columns'=>array(
  'employee_no', 
    ....
  'date_created',
  array(        
   'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'template'=>'{update} {delete}',
  ),            
 ),     ));
?>
```

What is the problem?

---

controller

```
 public function actionIndex()
        {
                // here is your code for this action
                $model = new Emp;
                //              print_r ($_POST);
                if(isset($_POST['Emp'])) {
                 ..
                 ..
                 $connection = Yii::app()->db2 ; //Connect with 2nd db.
                 ..
                 ..  
                 $command1 = 'Insert Query' // Insert Query here
                 $cmd1 = $connection->createCommand($command1);
                 $cmd1->execute();

                  }

                $this->render('index', array(
                                        'model'=>$model,
                                        'id'=>$model->extension,
                                        ));

        }


       public function actionUpdate($id)
        {
                $model=$this->loadModel($id);

                // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
                // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

                if(isset($_POST['Emp']))
                {
                        $model->attributes=$_POST['Emp'];
                        if($model->save())
                                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->emp_id));
                }

                $this->render('update',array(
                        'model'=>$model,
                ));
        }
```

model

```
class Emp extends DB2
{

 public function getDbConnection()
        {
                //return self::getCCDbConnection();
                return Yii::app()->dbcc;
        }
..
..
..

public function ExtensionList()
 {      
   $criteria=new CDbCriteria;
   $criteria->select='emp_id,emp_type,..date_created';
   $criteria->condition = "emp_type = 'USER'";

  return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
   'criteria'=>$criteria,
   'pagination' => array( 'pageSize' => 5 ),
  ));           
}
..
..
..

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not passing the id value to the update button in the grid. Change your gridview like below :

```
......
......
'template'=>'{update} {delete}',
'buttons'=>array
        (
         'update'=>array
            (
                'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("employes/update",$params=array("id"=>$data->emp_id))',
            ),
          'delete'=>array
          (
            'url'=>'Yii::app()->createUrl("employes/delete",$params=array("id"=>$data->emp_id))',
          )   
        )
......
......
```

Comment: I'm getting error as `Undefined variable: model`. I have generated code using `gii` thats working fine without passing id value. how?

Comment: Try $data instead of model.

Comment: Thanks, I have used $data its working.  Whay we need to parse the id here?

Comment: Because you are using a grid and for button icons (update etc) we need to associate the id of that particular record with the icon in that row. I am not sure about what you said regarding gii, IIRC I still needed to parse it after creating the view/form in gii, or I may be missing something. Anyway, glad you got it working.